# Can "allow" be followed by a gerund?

Tags: gerunds

I have come across an interesting opinion of a native speaker. They claim the following:

> 1. The Council's decision allowed (the) building of the new swimming pool to go ahead. CORRECT
> 2. The Council's decision allowed building the new swimming pool to go ahead. WRONG
> 3. Zoo regulations do not allow feeding the animals by visitors. WRONG
> 4. Zoo regulations do not allow feeding of the animals by visitors. CORRECT

Do you agree? If yes, how can you explain the difference?

Comment: 2 and 3 are wrong because the verb "allow" does not permit gerund-participial clauses as complement, but only infinitival ones. In 1 and 4 "building" and "feeding" are nouns. Further, "allow" is a catenative verb which occurs only in complex catenatives, the kind where there is an intervening NP between the verbs, as in "Ed allowed the students to go home early".

Comment: However I can see this example in a dictionary: We don’t allow diving in the pool.

Comment: "Diving" is a noun in that example, cf. "We don't allow even occasional diving in the pool".

Comment: How do you know that "diving" is not a gerund? It's hard to see it for me.

Comment: "Diving" is a noun because it can take adjectival premodification, as in the example I gave you, where it's modified by the adjective "occasional". Verbs can't be modified by adjectives.